# get ids group by range django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have:
Model:

```
id = PrimaryKey()
value = IntegerField()
```

I would like to get list of ids group by value range between `1-7` and `8-30` and `>30`.
What would be the **efficient** way to do so?
Or shall I write query for each range like:

```
one= Model.objects.filter(value__gt=0,value__lte=7).values_list(id)
two= Model.objects.filter(value__gt=7,value__lte=30).values_list(id)
three= Model.objects.filter(value__gt=30).values_list(id)
```

...
can I do so via `aggregate Count`? I want minimum database transactions.

## Updated:

Actually am trying to get how many products are sold, If they expires soon, then weekly count  else monthly like:

- Milk expires in 3 days. How many milk packets were sold in past 3
  days
- Bread expires in 7 days. How many bread were sold in past 7 days.

here `value` is `expires_in` i.e. in how many days a product expires in 
`(expiry date - mfg date)`

Model is like:

**InvoiceBreakup**

```
product_id
name
desctiption
expires_in
```

Comment: Do you need to counts, or the ids?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Updated Question please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With `groupby`

If you need the `ids`, we can use `groupby` of `itertools` for this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def rank(itm):
    vl = itm['value']
    if vl <= 7:
        return 0
    elif vl <= 30:
        return 1
    return 2

dat = {
    k: list(map(itemgetter('id'),v))
    for k, v in groupby(
        Model.objects.filter(value__gt=0).values('id', 'value').order_by('value'),
        rank)
}
```

Now `dat` will contain three elements: `0` contains the list of elements in the range of `1-7`, `1` for elements in the range `8-30` and `2` in are `id`s with value 30+.

We can thus then obtain the list of `ids`, with:

```
dat[0]  # ids with value 1-7
dat[1]  # ids with value 8-30
dat[2]  # ids with value 31+
```

This will result in a single query, and we let Python do the grouping. This can be slow if the data is huge, but it will already get quite slow, since the deserializing of the elements also will take comparable effort.

## Optimizing the checks

We can let the database perform the logic to determine the category, and thus move some work from Python to the database:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value

qs = Model.objects.filter(value__gt=0).annotate(
    cat = Case(
        When(value__lt=8, then=Value(0)),
        When(value__lt=31, then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(2),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
).values('id', 'cat').order_by('cat')
```

and then construct the dictionary with:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

data = {
    k: list(map(itemgetter('id'), v))
    for k, v in groupby(qs, itemgetter('cat'))
}
```

Comment: Sir can I also get count? As described in updated question section.

Comment: You can call the `len(..)` on the lists, if you are *only* interested in the count, then the query can be done more efficient. But if you are interested in the `id`s as well, then it is better to "*piggyback*" on the work done by the part that classifies the ids.