# How to get count of particular attribute [age_group e.g] in the following Django Query based on Ranges?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am using Django 2.2.
I have the following `models.py` in Django.

```
class Study(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    age_group = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now I have some values that are filled using the form which are as follows :

```
age_group - 13  gender - male
age_group - 27  gender - female 
age_group - 20  gender - male
```

Now I want to `group` `age_group` type based on the ranges. For e.g my output should be :

```
age_group 5-21  Count : 2
age_group 22 - 30  Count : 1
```

I have tried the following query: But I am stuck with the group part.

Here's the query I have tried so far :

```
Study.objects.filter(Q(age_group__range=[10,20])| Q(age_group__range=[21,35]) | Q(age_group__range=[36, 54])).values('age_group').annotate(Sum('age_group')).order_by('age_group')
```

Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: I think you can find a similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928253/get-ids-group-by-range-django